# how to create aroundplugin for abstractentity?

Tags: magento2.3, around-plugin

I have created around plugin for isAttributeValid function for Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity but it is not working.
code:
`<type name="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity">
 <plugin name="bbb" type="xxxx\yyy\Plugin\Entity\AbstractEntity" sortOrder="10" />
</type>`

in the plugin:

```
<?php
namespace XXX\YYY\Plugin\Entity;

class AbstractEntity
{
    public function aroundIsAttributeValid(
        $subject, $attrCode, $result) {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('hhhuu'); 
        echo "hhh";exit();
        $returnValue = $subject;
        return $returnValue;

    }

}
```

but echo is not printed.

Comment: what is the location of di.xml ?

Comment: Global location

Comment: could you plz tell when `isAttributeValid` is called ?

Comment: It was called in Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product.php

Comment: I want to ask, in admin when `IsAttributeValid` is called so i can check override is working or not

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a log file -  
`$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Your text message');`

Comment: log file is not created

Comment: Post the whole plugin code

Comment: updated the plugin code

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your method name:

`aroundisAttributeValid` should be `aroundIsAttributeValid` (note the capital "I"). Also, I'm not sure if your parameter `$result` should exist - you may need to check that.
Another thing, you may need to check the scope (frontend, admin, global) in which you're defining the plugin. This can also influence if it works or not.

Comment: I have changed aroundIsAttributeValid .still it is not working